# ¿Guardar datos de un usuario logueado?

Tags: swift

Estoy haciendo una app registro login en swift (Xcode 7)

hago el login correctamente
paso a la siguiente pantalla de Perfil
En la pantalla perfil hay un botón que me lleva a un view controller que es añadir pacientes a ese usuario loguedo.
Para mantener el usuario creo una variable de sesión con este código:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usuario.text, forKey: "nombre")                     
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
let userid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nombre") as! Usuario
```

Uso Core data Usuario y Paciente

En la clase que controla el viewController donde introduzco el nombre y el apellido hago lo siguiente:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entidadPaciente = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Pacient", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
let paciente = Pacient(entity: entidadPaciente!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
paciente.nombre = nombrePaciente.text
paciente.apellidos = apellidoPaciente.text

paciente.medico?.nombre = userid
do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Este último código se corresponde a lo que realiza un botón pero me falla en `paciente.medico?.nombre = userid` y no sé por qué.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: userId es de tipo Usuario y paciente.medico?.nombre tiene pinta de ser de tipo  String, puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que haya un error de tipo de datos...

Cuando haces:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usuario.text, forKey: "nombre")
```

estás guardando un `String` (supongo que eso es lo que es `usuario.text`), pero luego lo tratas de obtener como un `Usuario`:

```
let userid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nombre") as! Usuario
```

Por último, tratas de asignar un `Usuario` a un `String`:

```
paciente.medico?.nombre = userid
```